# add to deepest array child element

Tags: php, arrays

How do I select the deepest child element from a multidimensional-array in order to add another element to that specific one in php (always knowing where it is added, so in case additional information from the parent is needed in order to create the new child)?

eg. having an array like this I want to be able to add another aaaa, bbbb, cccc to each: aaa, bbb, ccc? and later on aaaaa, bbbbb,… to each aaaa, bbbb… and so on (where each new element is aware of it's parent's name).

```
array(
"a"=> array(
    "aa"=> array(
       "aaa",
       "bbb",
       "ccc"
       ),
    "bb"=> array(
       "aaa",
       "bbb",
       "ccc"
       ),
    "aa"=> array(
       "aaa",
       "bbb",
       "ccc"
       ),
    ),
"b"=> array(
    "aa"=> array(
       "aaa",
       "bbb",
       "ccc"
       ),
    "bb"=> array(
       "aaa",
       "bbb",
       "ccc"
       ),
    "aa"=> array(
       "aaa",
       "bbb",
       "ccc"
       ),
    ),
"c"=> array(
    "aa"=> array(
       "aaa",
       "bbb",
       "ccc"
       ),
       […]
    ),
);
```

Comment: real examples are easier to understand (for me at least)

Comment: array_walk_recursive sounds perfect for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php). It lets you itterate over all the leafs of a multidimensional array.

```
function add_children(&$item, $key)
{
    //Here you can change item to something else (since we use &)
    $item = array('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc');
}

array_walk_recursive($array, 'add_children');
```

*Disclaimar: I have not tested this code.*

Comment: As far as I understand, this visits the leaf nodes only. Is there also a way which loops through each possible path, in case additional information from the parent is needed in order to create the new child?

Comment: You are correct in that it only visit leaf nodes. As I understand your question as it is currently asked, that should be enough so I will not edit my answer. If you need information about the "path" to the leaf you will need to switch approach and implement your own recursion. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447664/get-parent-array-name-after-array-walk-recursive-function) question might provide some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion for this. I'm not sure if your example is indicative of how your actual data will look, but in this case the deepest elements are NOT arrays, so you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$testArray = array(
  'a' => array(
    'aa' => array(
      'aaa',
      'bbb'
    )
  )
);

print_r(modifyArray($testArray));

function modifyArray($array)
{
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      $array[$key] = modifyArray($value);
    } else {
      $array[$value] = $value . substr($value, 0, 1);
      unset($array[$key]);
    }
  }

  return $array;
}
```