# Get section name by key name of an ini file in php

Tags: php, ini

I have an ini file which looks like this:

```
[236a4e392b6dd0a8409bb91c664ab6468be32555]
76561197961658420=DaRoL
76561197962180350=Spow
76561197962376928=Kolma

[efd3dd758092ad90e35fb634a203c41b90da6333]
76561197964385070=Kelininkas
76561199641652847=Kelininkas
```

How is it possible in PHP to return the section name by searching with a key name (or optional key value).

e.g. 76561197964385070 -> efd3dd758092ad90e35fb634a203c41b90da6333 and optional

Kelininkas -> efd3dd758092ad90e35fb634a203c41b90da6333

I imported the ini file into an array and I'm able to find the key and item.

But not the key name of the superordinate key.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');

$ini_array = (parse_ini_file("BannedHWs.ini",true));

$steamid="76561197962180330";

function find($item, $key)

{   

    global $steamid;    
    if ($key == $steamid)
    echo "$key FOUND $item\n";

}

array_walk_recursive($ini_array, 'find');

echo "\n";
print_r ($ini_array); // SHOW ARRAY

?>
```

Result:

```
76561197962180330 FOUND Spow

Array
(
    [236a4e392b6dd0a8409bb91c664ab6468be32d15] => Array
        (
            [76561197961658460] => DaRoL
            [76561197962180330] => Spow
            [76561197962376938] => Kolma
        )

    [efd3dd758092ad90e35fb634a203c41b90da6895] => Array
        (
            [76561197964385060] => Kelininkas
            [76561199641652827] => Kelininkas
        )

)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello. We're here to help you, not to write code for you. Show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts with us and we'll help you - but nobody is going to write code for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added some information about my current code, but I'm still trying to figure out how I can get the first Level Key name of that multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a linux machine, this might help you. This is not a solution, but a path where you can go further.

```
$ cat some_config_ini.txt 
[efd3dd758092ad90e35fb634a203c41b90da6333]
76561197964385070=Kelininkas
76561199641652847=Kelininkas
$ cat some_config_ini.txt | grep Kelininkas -B 1 | head -1
[efd3dd758092ad90e35fb634a203c41b90da6333]
```

Above commands will not work with your original file.

```
$ cat som_config_ini.txt | grep Spow -B 1 | head -1
76561197961658420=DaRoL
```

However if you know know the key&values under a block, you can try this.

```
$ cat som_config_ini.txt | grep Spow -B 2 | head -1
[236a4e392b6dd0a8409bb91c664ab6468be32555]
$ cat som_config_ini.txt | grep Kolma -B 3 | head -1
[236a4e392b6dd0a8409bb91c664ab6468be32555]
```

Be aware of the arguments passed to grep [-B 1/2/3].

I can offer ruby&python solutions if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');

$ini_array = (parse_ini_file("BannedHWs.ini",true));

$steamid="76561199641652827";


function findID(array $array, $path = null) {
    global $steamid;
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (!is_array($v)) {
            if ($k == $steamid){
            echo "HWID: $path\n";
            }
        }
        else {           
            findID($v, $path.$k);
        }
    }
}

findID($ini_array);

//echo "\n";
//print_r ($ini_array); // SHOW ARRAY

?>
```

Based on:

[get parent array name after array_walk_recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447664/get-parent-array-name-after-array-walk-recursive-function)